# How to set up caching for css/js static properly

Tags: apache, caching, browser, client-side

to prevent problem, when I update CSS/JS media files and browsers dont request new version, because they cache these files I used this solution: https://github.com/jaddison/django-cachebuster, that adds ?<timestamp of file> to CSS/JS filenames (replaces /media/main.css with /media/main.css?20012931203128. I assumed that it will force browsers to reload css file when timestamp is changed (file is updated) and use local cached version in other case. But what I see in Apache logs (and at firebug) is that browsers (at least Firefox) requests CSS/JS files for each reload of the page, even after getting 304 code, see fragment from logs:

```
XXX.255.115.60 - - [24/Jul/2011:04:17:25 -0700] "GET /media/main.css?333900240611 HTTP/1.1" 304 172 "" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1; rv:2.0.1) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/4.0.1"
XXX.255.115.60 - - [24/Jul/2011:04:17:26 -0700] "GET /media/main.js?270101180511 HTTP/1.1" 304 173 "" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1; rv:2.0.1) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/4.0.1"
XXX.255.115.60 - - [24/Jul/2011:04:17:34 -0700] "GET /media/main.css?333900240611 HTTP/1.1" 304 172 "" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1; rv:2.0.1) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/4.0.1"
XXX.255.115.60 - - [24/Jul/2011:04:17:35 -0700] "GET /media/main.js?270101180511 HTTP/1.1" 304 173 "" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1; rv:2.0.1) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/4.0.1"
XXX.255.115.60 - - [24/Jul/2011:04:17:44 -0700] "GET /media/main.css?333900240611 HTTP/1.1" 304 172 "" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1; rv:2.0.1) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/4.0.1"
XXX.255.115.60 - - [24/Jul/2011:04:17:44 -0700] "GET /media/main.js?270101180511 HTTP/1.1" 304 173 "" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1; rv:2.0.1) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/4.0.1"
```

Of course, it makes my website slower. Is it possible to force browsers to update files only when timestamp after .css?... is changed?
Thanks!

**Upd:**
Here is an example of response & request:

**Request**

```
User-Agent  Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-GB; rv:1.9.2.18) Gecko/20110614 Firefox/3.6.18
Accept  text/css,*/*;q=0.1
Accept-Language en-gb,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding gzip,deflate
Accept-Charset  ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7
Keep-Alive  115
Referer 
DNT 1
Connection  keep-alive
If-Modified-Since   Fri, 24 Jun 2011 05:39:33 GMT
If-None-Match   "8ed02f1-a21-4a66ea04f2f40"
```

**Response**

```
Date    Sun, 24 Jul 2011 12:28:21 GMT
Server  Apache
Connection  Keep-Alive
Keep-Alive  timeout=2, max=99
Etag    "8ed02f1-a21-4a66ea04f2f40"
```

**Initial resp**

```
Date    Sun, 24 Jul 2011 12:51:05 GMT
Server  Apache
Last-Modified   Fri, 24 Jun 2011 05:39:33 GMT
Etag    "8ed02f1-a21-4a66ea04f2f40"
Accept-Ranges   bytes
Content-Length  2593
Keep-Alive  timeout=2, max=99
Connection  Keep-Alive
Content-Type    text/css
```

Comment: How does the response header of such a request look like?

Comment: Gumbo, I updated an original question with these details.

Comment: And how does the response to the initial request look like?

Comment: You are talking about response to get a page (not page components?) It looks like this Date Sun, 24 Jul 2011 12:44:45 GMT
Server Apache
Vary Cookie,Accept-Encoding
Set-Cookie csrftoken=...; Max-Age=31449600; Path=/ sessionid=...; expires=Sun, 07-Aug-2011 12:44:46 GMT; Max-Age=1209600; Path=/
Content-Encoding gzip
Content-Length 2294
Keep-Alive timeout=2, max=100
Connection Keep-Alive
Content-Type text/html; charset=utf-8

Comment: I mean the response to the request before it gets cached. The request/response you showed is already a conditional request for the validation of an already cached response.

Comment: Gumbo, I updated my post with response, that I got with 200 code after clearing my cache in browser.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use proper [HTTP caching](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-13) directives to make the responses [never expire](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#page-127) (one year in future):

```
Cache-Control: max-age=31536000
Expires: Sun, 24 Jul 2012 12:51:05 GMT
```

You can do this in Apache with [mod_expires](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_expires.html):

```
ExpiresByType text/css "now plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType text/javascript "now plus 1 year"
```

Comment: I'm afraid this won't help. As I wrote in my answer, I think the problem is somewhere else. It is not in the browsers decision to cache or not to cache, but in the Apache's behaviour. If I remember think I tried something similar and it was a dead end.

Comment: @Tomas Telensky: No, it’s the client that decides whether to cache a response or not. And it does it based on the request/response.

Comment: Well, but if there is a query string the browser must always ask the server because it doesn't now if it isn't generated dynamically. And then it's up to the server to respond properly, but Apache doesn't - see my answer.

Comment: Hi Gumbo, I applied you recomendation, initial answer now is http://dumpz.org/69932/, but I still see requests for js/css files in apache log. Interesting, that repsponse size is 100-200 bytes, it means, that files are not transfered (I guess, only 304 code), but browser doesn't understand, that it should not query these files.

Comment: ... exactly what I expected :-)

Comment: @Tomas Telensky: No, that doesn’t matter (theoretically). HTTP doesn’t distinguish static or dynamically generated responses. Although some clients may do this.

Comment: Yes, but the number of requests for media files is small, probably there are issues with some cliens. Because for my browser when I have Gumbo's lines in my htaccess it doesn't fetch css/js files, and when I removed them it requests full size files. I need some time to make checks & analyze logs, but looks like it mostly works

Answer (score 1):

I played with this a lot and I found that it is probably caused by an **[Apache bug](https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=40953)**. This is not problem of the browser - once the timesatmp is in a query string, the browser doesn't understand the query string and must at least ask the server if it hasn't changed. The Apache responds well with '304 Not modified', but it always sends the file too!

I made a lot of experiment and the only solution that worked was to **place the timestamp directly to file name**. In PHP, I use the following function:

```
function safe_inline_url($file)
{

     $basename = basename($file);
     if (strstr($basename, '.'))
          return dirname($file) . "/" .
               preg_replace('/(\.[^\.]*)$/', '_ts_' . filemtime($file) . '\1',
                    $basename);
     else 
          return $file . '_ts_' . filemtime($file);

}
```

which modifies any inline URL (css, js, images, ...) so that it adds timestamp, eg. like **js/forms.js** => **js/forms_ts_1278080148.js** .

At the server, you must then rewrite the modified filenames back to the real names, which is accomplished by putting this to your .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}      ^(.*)_ts_[0-9]{9,}$
RewriteRule ^                   %1      [PT]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}      ^(.*)_ts_[0-9]{9,}\.(.*)$
RewriteRule ^                   %1.%2   [PT]
```

you put it to root directory and you also must put it to **every subdirectory's .htaccess with RewriteEngine On**.

The only issue was with scriptaculous javascript library which uses URLs to include other sources - you cannot use this trick to include their js files.

Comment: Thanks, Tomas. I thought about it too, this method is not included into django-cachedbuster, so I prefered to ask before writing my own code :)

Comment: Well, I recommend to use this, it works for me several years (see http://birds.cz/ for example).