# SIte shows old pages in cache - I've reset htaccess to disable caching but it doesn't work

Tags: .htaccess, caching, cache-control

I'm in a pickle here. I tried to set up caching using htaccess files. I made the mistake of setting the htaccess to maintain a cache of html and text files as well. The result was that since the site is a dynamic web application the html would be always generated based upon whatever activity is taking place on the site. However it keeps showing old cache.

I removed all entries from the htaccess file concerning the caching and even deleted my local cache. However its not working. What do I do here.

---

What happened was that I had put in the following code in the htaccess file:

```
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresByType text/html "access plus 30 days"

ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 60 days"
ExpiresByType image/jpg "access plus 60 days"
ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 60 days" 
ExpiresByType application/x-javascript "access plus 60 days"

ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 60 days"
ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access plus 360 days"
</IfModule>
```

The first line in the snippt was the blunder here. Because of this I could only access old cached pages even though information on the site changes drastically. I removed the entire line however it hasn't worked at all as even now after having cleared my browsers cache hundreds of times I am still seeing cached results.

Comment: Hard to say what is your problem here. Look at this if it helps you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6806463/how-to-set-up-caching-for-css-js-static-properly/6806703#comment-8082992 . Maybe you wanted to accomplish the same thing? If yes, then try to remove everything you tried in your .htaccess and try the solution proposed.